# Debugging PHP production application with XDebug when need?

Tags: php, xdebug

I have a question on debugging PHP application using XDebug in production and would like to have your idea.

We all know that even if the testing and production environments are identical, we still have bugs that exists in Production but not testing.

So, is that possible to show XDebug detail information/profiling **ONLY** when pass in something like `enable_debug=1` in URL, and XDebug will show every custom debug information possible?

While if there is no such parameters, everything is running just like normal.

Can XDebug do that?  If not, what other debugging program can do this?

Thank you.

P.S. I know clearly that:

- We cannot put debugging information in production.
- This is dangerous and not security-friendly when showing debug info in production server.
- As I said before, Programming is weird.  Even we confirm that everything is identical, some bugs will only exists in production but not testing.

Comment: That's very similar to what the standard `XDEBUG_SESSION` cookie does already ([ref.](https://xdebug.org/docs/step_debug)). I think the most important thing to do is that restrict the whole feature to a set of well known IP addresses. Still, it doesn't feel quite right. Running the Xdebug extension always adds overhead. Many production bugs can be diagnosed with a copy of the database.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could use GET parameter, like:

```
if ($_GET['enable_debug'] == 1) {
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('xdebug.show_error_trace', 1);
    ini_set('xdebug.show_exception_trace', 1);
    // other XDebug settings...
}
```

However, this approach doesn't take into account security concerns and might expose sensitive information if the `enable_debug` parameter is ever unintentionally or maliciously set.

Comment: This is not a great idea. You also will need to set `xdebug.mode` from `off` to `debug,develop`, which you can't do with `ini_set()`. Having `xdebug.mode` set to anything else in production (which you never should do!) has a performance impact.